# Disabling stopping of video by clicking on screen in Vimeo

Tags: javascript, video, vimeo

I am trying to figure out following "issue" that I have with Vimeo Player (I am using Vimeo Plus for better functionality).

a) I would like to try to disable the option that when an user clicks on the video, the video stops. Even though I hide almost everything, the video still can be stopped by clicking on it when it is playing. I would like to try to disable this. Or disable any interaction of user with the video (e.g. mouse cursor is disabled or ignored in area of video).

b) If above is not possible I would like to at least display to the user an alternative message, for example "You have stopped the video. Please click on the video again to play it."  or when the user stops it to auto-play the video again.

Thank you for any suggestions for an answer or information leading to an answer.

To explain a bit further. The development is ongoing inside a platform called Qualtrics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualtrics).

**The basic code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Experiment</title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div style="text-align: center;">
   <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" mozallowfullscreen=""src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/ANONYM?autoplay=1&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="640">
   </iframe>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

I am not able to figure out how to disable it. Therefore I am posting only the current code with auto-play and the features that I know how to use.

Comment: What does your code looks like?

Comment: Provide your attempts at coding this and we will help.

Comment: You could place an empty div with the same size above the player, so the user can't click on the player directly. As I can read from your answer you don't plan any interaction anyway.

Comment: I have added a code that I currently use and works. It is without the feature I am asking about because I am not sure how should I do it. Sorry for not including it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create another layer (an empty div) under your iframe which will catch all events.

Sample:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Vimeo</title>
  </head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #box {

      position: absolute; 
      width: 640px;
      height: 360px;
      margin-top: -360px;
      border: 2px solid green;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/83611065?color=ff9933&autoplay=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen autoplay></iframe>
    <div id="box"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/meqog7qt/)

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. I did use your code. There was one thing that made me curious though. Within the #box {, there is pice of code "margin-top: -360px". When I had used this in this value, the box was not exactly around the video and was actually leaving about 3-4 px space at the top. I used "-366px" and then it was okay. Why do you think this happened?

Comment: Hello. You should remove this style: `border: 2px solid green;`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped.